# Why doesn’t my C array code work as expected?

Tags: objective-c

I have a pointer in objective c, that called :

```
 int *binary[20] ;
```

which later returned as a pointer .

When i am trying to assign a number to it with :

```
binary[5]=1;
```

i get error.

I know that `binary` points to an address of the first cell from 20 cells .
Why cant i get directly into cell number 5 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition `int* binary[20]` defines an array of 20 pointers to `int`. Is that really what you want, or did you mean `int binary[20]` to create an array of 20 `int`s?

Either way, the resulting array is stored on the stack, so that it is an error to return a pointer to this array to some calling code. (After you return to calling code, the stack gets unwound and the memory reserved for your array is marked as free.)
 If you want to work with the array from calling code, you have to allocate in on the heap:

```
int *binary = calloc(20, sizeof(int));
binary[5] = 1; // fine, even after returning from this function
```

This gets you a pointer to memory that’s available even after returning from the function. (And the caller bears the responsibility to release that memory using `free`.)

Anyway, unless you have some specific requirements you should use `NSArray` or a similar collection class instead. The general rule in Objective-C is to use as high-level APIs as possible, until forced to do otherwise. Allocating an `NSArray` for several integers is perfectly acceptable in the general case.

Answer (score 0):

You have declare a array of pointer.

It means you can store 20 memory address in that array.

But by `binary[5]=1;`  you are tying to store integer in that instead of address of int.

You can not store address like static value.

Comment: `1` is a valid address of an `int`, so that the posted code should work.

Answer (score 0):

You declared array of pointers to integer. Your type is `int *`.

If you change the type to `int`, it will work:

```
int binary[20];
binary[5] = 1;
```

---

Btw, your Q has nothing to do with Objective-C, but with C. In Objective-C you are encouraged to work with objects as much as possible. (`NSArray` and `NSValue`).

Comment: Note that `1` is a valid pointer, so that his original code works just fine.

Comment: `1` is not valid pointer unless you turn off all compiler warnings. Also _compiles_ != _works_.

Comment: I had the implicit-integer-to-pointer-conversion warning off, that’s why my compiler didn’t complain. Also, the original code would not just compile, but also *work* fine, unless the pointer gets returned to the calling code. (Not that confusing pointers and integers is a good idea.)